# Has anyone succeeded in getting Eclipse's "Report bug or enhancement..." to work?

Tags: eclipse

Here it fails every time, on multiple installations, with "Unexpected error while creating task for this report" https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW09g.png .

I'm using "Eclipse for PHP Developers" latest version - 2018-09 (4.9.0).

EDIT: Further info:

I got the error after clicking Finish https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjSd5.png . I don't use the same workspace for both. I don't have a proxy. I did not knowingly try to report it anonymously, but the failing operation did not ask for any ID. This was on fairly new installations.

EDIT: Error details

```
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
```

and

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.bugs 4 0 2018-11-04 22:03:08.842
!MESSAGE Unexpected error while creating task for error report
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error retrieving task attributes from repository.

Premature end of file.
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaRepositoryConnector.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaRepositoryConnector.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaTaskDataHandler.initializeTaskData(BugzillaTaskDataHandler.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.util.TasksUiInternal.createTaskData(TasksUiInternal.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.AttributeTaskMapper.createTaskData(AttributeTaskMapper.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.TaskErrorReporter.process(TaskErrorReporter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.TaskErrorReporter$1.run(TaskErrorReporter.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui.CommonUiUtil$1.run(CommonUiUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature end of file.
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.AbstractReportFactory.collectResults(AbstractReportFactory.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.RepositoryConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationFactory.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaClient.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaClient.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaRepositoryConnector.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaRepositoryConnector.java:751)
    ... 7 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla 4 1 2018-11-04 22:03:08.843
!MESSAGE Error retrieving task attributes from repository.

Premature end of file.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Premature end of file.
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.AbstractReportFactory.collectResults(AbstractReportFactory.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.RepositoryConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationFactory.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaClient.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaClient.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaRepositoryConnector.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaRepositoryConnector.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaTaskDataHandler.initializeTaskData(BugzillaTaskDataHandler.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.util.TasksUiInternal.createTaskData(TasksUiInternal.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.AttributeTaskMapper.createTaskData(AttributeTaskMapper.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.TaskErrorReporter.process(TaskErrorReporter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.TaskErrorReporter$1.run(TaskErrorReporter.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui.CommonUiUtil$1.run(CommonUiUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

The same issue on Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers gave:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error retrieving task attributes from repository.

Premature end of file.
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaRepositoryConnector.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaRepositoryConnector.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaTaskDataHandler.initializeTaskData(BugzillaTaskDataHandler.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.util.TasksUiInternal.createTaskData(TasksUiInternal.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.AttributeTaskMapper.createTaskData(AttributeTaskMapper.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.TaskErrorReporter.process(TaskErrorReporter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.bugs.TaskErrorReporter$1.run(TaskErrorReporter.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui.CommonUiUtil$1.run(CommonUiUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature end of file.
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.AbstractReportFactory.collectResults(AbstractReportFactory.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.RepositoryConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationFactory.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaClient.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaClient.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.bugzilla.core.BugzillaRepositoryConnector.getRepositoryConfiguration(BugzillaRepositoryConnector.java:751)
    ... 7 more
```

and

```
eclipse.buildId=4.8.0.I20180611-0500
java.version=1.8.0_191
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
```

Comment: To answer your question: yes. If you want to know, what does not work in your case, look into the _Error Log_ view.

Comment: Thanks. Was your success on this (the latest) version? I've added error log details.

Comment: Which Eclipse package do you use? _"Eclipse for PHP Developers"_ or `-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product` (which means _Eclipse for C/C++ Developers_)?

Comment: As I said in the Q: Eclipse for PHP Developers.

Comment: But oops, sorry, I see now the error details I posted are from the same issue on Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers. I have now added the Eclipse for PHP Developers error details.

Comment: Please add all error details to the question (in the _Error Log_ view double-click on an item and then click the button in the upper right). When do you exactly get the error? Do you use the same workspace for PHP and for C/C++? Do you have a proxy? Do you try to report it anonymously?

Comment: Those details are already present, no? I got the error after clicking Finish https://i.imgur.com/GcCZHI3.png . I don't use the same workspace for both. I don't have a proxy. I did not knowingly try to report it anonymously, but the failing operation did not ask for any ID.

Comment: Clicking Finish should open a _New Task_ editor here. Does the view _Task Repositories_ contain the item _Bugs > Eclipse.org_? Your question currently contains in error details only the content of the two text areas of the error details dialog, but not e. g. the date (use the button _Copy Event Details To Clipboard_ instead).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [**Eclipse bug 527895**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=527895) which occurs with a new workspace.

If the workspace is old enough, the feature can be used, otherwise it fails with the known error dialog.

Please leave a comment that *Help > Report Bug or Enhancement...* is also affected by this bug.

Comment: I couldn't say, from that description. But yes, these were indeed newish installations. I've added that note here and will comment there about your suggestion link. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with a newer workspace and get the `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` error. With this, it was easy to find the bug because the error is mentioned in [comment 2](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=527895#c2). Do you have an older workspace that can be used as a workaround?

Comment: I don't have an older workspace from "Eclipse for PHP Developers". But it seems I've been gifted a workaround. The command now succeeds -- both on the workspace on which it previously failed, and on two new test workspaces. Odd!